# Join function SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, inner-join

I am having two tables: `INFORGAIN200 (WORD, IG)` and `TF (FILEID, WORD, T_FREQ).` In the `INFOGAIN200` table I have only 200 words, in the TF there are a lot more. Now I want to inner join `INFOGAIN200` to `TF` based on the descendent ranking of `T_FREQ` in TF. Below is my code.

```
SELECT B.FILEID, B.WORD, TF.T_FREQ
FROM (SELECT * FROM TF, ORDER BY T_FREQ DESC) INNER JOIN INFOGAIN200 B
ON B.WORD=TF.WORD;
```

Here is the error code: `ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"`. The error points to `ORDER BY`. Please suggest how to walk around this. Thanks.

Comment: Looks there is no , required in SELECT * FROM TF , ORDER

Comment: `ORDER BY` looks not valid, moreover, you forgot to alias your subquery, that's why you are getting the "invalid table name". `FROM (SELECT * FROM TF, ORDER BY T_FREQ DESC) TF INNER ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT B.FILEID, B.WORD, TF.T_FREQ
FROM TF INNER JOIN INFOGAIN200 B
ON B.WORD=TF.WORD
ORDER BY TF.T_FREQ DESC;
```

Anyways FYI, you cannot use ORDER BY clause inside derived tables. You will get error

*The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.*